# EF Core 2.0 Invalid Column Error from ASP.NET Core UserManager

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core

Have started new ASP.NET Core 2.0 and EF Core 2.0 project. The project uses the built in Identity table schema. Every time I make any call to the built in UserManager that uses any of the Roles or Claims tables the call fails with a "Invalid Column" error. I added Serilog so I could see all logging and EF Core generated SQL.  EF Core is adding the same invalid column name "BlogUserId" to all the select queries that are failing thus the invalid column error. That string does not exist in the code anywhere including the EF Core Migrations code that generates the database and tables.  Where is Entity Framework picking up this column?

```
SELECT TOP(1) [e].[UserId], [e].[RoleId], [e].[BlogUserId]
FROM [AspNetUserRoles] AS [e]
WHERE ([e].[UserId] = @__get_Item_0) AND ([e].[RoleId] = @__get_Item_1)
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): 
Invalid column name 'BlogUserId'.
```

You can see where the column gets added to the generated query but that column is not part of the table schema nor is it in code anywhere.  How do I fix this issue or can someone tell me what is causing this?

Thanks to Ivan Stoev the solution was found.  The BlogUser class was a carry over from the old web site which was ASP.NET Core 1.1. It had additional properties but also had two navigation properties as below to store user Roles and Claims which had worked perfectly. After commenting these to navigation properties every thing seems to work as expected.

```
public virtual ICollection<IdentityUserRole<string>> Roles { get; } = new   List<IdentityUserRole<string>>();
public virtual ICollection<IdentityUserClaim<string>> Claims { get; } = new List<IdentityUserClaim<string>>();
```

Comment: Can't be said w/o seeing the `BlogUser` class. Most probably a collection/list/enumerable property identified as navigation property, hence relationship.

Comment: Thanks Ivan you were right on target. It was two navigation properties causing the issues.